# Adding Street View controls (the two icons just above the +) to a Google Map (v3)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

It's probably something really simple, but I can't find it in the docs and I can't find a map with it to check it's source...

I use **version 3** of the API.

I guess it's an something to add in *myOptions*?

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
var myOptions = {
                 zoom: 8,
                 center: latlng,
                 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                }
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);
```

Currently I only have dragging controls and the zoom pane controls. I would like to have the two Street View controls icons too.

If you want full source, I'm using [this example](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/examples/map-simple.html) as a base (how would you add Street View controls to this example?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Streetview support has recently been added to the V3 API.

Within MyOptions, you will need to add the variable streetViewControl: true.

A demonstration is available from:
http://homepage.ntlworld.com/keir.clarke/web/v3.htm

Information is also available from the V3 methods library:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MapOptions